# VIM: How to make buffer/register permanent?

Tags: vim, buffer

I have a probably very beginners question about registers in vim (MacVim): Why are the last registers vanishing after a new yank? Here my explanation; hope it is clear. Probably this question seems dump, but I am unable to find a solution in `:help register`. How to make register permanent? I need at least 10 text snippets over and over again ...

Thank you for help

marek

```
# Starting point:
abc
def
ghi
jkl

# inserted yanked lines by `p`
abc
def
ghi

# What is in the register?
1. Step (abc): 

:reg 

  l  ""   abc^J
  l  "0   abc^J  

2. Step (def) 

:reg

  l  ""   def^J
  l  "0   def^J 

abc vanished from the register

3. Step (gef)

:reg

  l  ""   ghi^J
  l  "0   ghi^J 

abc and def vanished from the register
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with the normal system clipboard, the value on the clipboard will be overwritten as well. The vim's unnamed register works in a very similar way to it.

You can use the 26 named registers `"a-z` like `"aY` to yank a line.
The yanked value won't be changed unless you overwrite it manually.

You can get detailed info: `:h registers`

Comment: Thx Kent for the fast reply. Could give me a hint how to create a `named register`?

Comment: @MarekStepanek have you read the help doc I mentioned in the answer? Apart from that, I've already told how to yank to named register: `"aY` when you want to paste, `"ap`. Read the doc pls.

Comment: Thx although your answer sounds impatient. I got it! Working!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a lot of snippets I would recommend using [ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips). You define a trigger for each snippet you need and the plugin inserts it like magic.

[image]